# How can I change a global variable's value from inside a function?

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swiftui, boolean

I have a `@State` boolean in my code inside the `struct` which I have a button that `toggle()`s it. However, I want to use that variable in my other views as well. So I need to have it outside `struct` so I can use it another place. My question is that how can I now change its value? Previously my `button`'s action `toggle`d it. How can I change it now?

Here is my code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var checked: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
     HStack {
            Button(action: {checked.toggle()}) {
                Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(height: 20)
            }
            Text("I agree")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

However, I want this **to work**:

```
var checked:Bool = false
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
     HStack {
            Button(action: {checked.toggle()}) {
                Image(systemName: checked ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .scaledToFit()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(height: 20)
            }
            Text("I agree")
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show your code for this?

Comment: I did share it.

Answer (score 3):

The possible solution is to use shared observable object with wrapped this property, then it can be observed in all dependent views.

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
class GlobalState: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = GlobalState()
    
    @Published var checked:Bool = false
}

struct myView: View {
    @ObservedObject var gs = GlobalState.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button(action: {gs.checked.toggle()}) {
                Image(systemName: gs.checked ? "checkmark.square": "square")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .frame(height: 20)
            }
            Text("I agree")
                .fontWeight(.bold)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: ```class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var globalState = GlobalState.shared

    init() {
        if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didLaunchBefore") && globalState.checked{   //Agreement s checked in OnBoardingView
            currentPage = "appView"
        } else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didLaunchBefore")
            currentPage = "onboardingView"
            
        }
    }
    
    @Published var currentPage: String
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked but when I add it to this class I get error.

Comment: 'self' captured by a closure before all members were initialized